# Having issue in deleting task, when I click on remove all tasks in my list remove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Having issue in deleting task. When I click on remove all tasks in my list remove from firebase and from page I want to remove the task on which I clicked remove.

> that's the code for remove task in reducer

```
case 'REMOVE_TASK':
        return  omit(state, action.payload);
```

> and that's my code in tasksItems for remove task

```
const removeTask = ({ id } = {}) => {
    const payload = {id:id}
        database.ref('tasks').remove().then(()=>{
            dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_TASK', payload})

            console.log('removed');
        })
            
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What does omit do? Can you sahre your code of that too?

Comment: @Domino987 check this git@github.com:jzebgul/mytodo.git

Comment: and if i use state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id); itsyays state.filter is not a function

Comment: omit(state, action.id)} I think this needs to be action.payload.id

Comment: const removeTask = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child('tasks');
        dbtasksWrapper.child(id).remove().then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_TASK', id: id })
            console.log('removed');
        }) its working